ChartJS v4 - Using Points in a line chart will result in all x-values at 0
I am facing a rather strange problem with line charts and ChartJS. Given the following very simple code. I expect to have a line chart where 3 data points (at x: 0, x:1 and x: 2). But instead, all points are shown at x:0. According to the docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#data-structure it should be possible to use the given notation to draw the line graph.


var data = {
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Bug Report",
      data: [
        { x: 0, y: 1 },
        { x: 1, y: 2 },
        { x: 2, y: 4 }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: data
});
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>


<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>




That's because your x axis remains of the default type "category", you have to set its type to "linear". Add options: {scales: {x: {type: "linear"}}}.

You, sir, are a lifesaver! Thanks. Can you write it as an official answer?

I'm glad it helped. No need for an answer, it's already here on stackoverflow in many questions and answers or messages - happens frequently.

The Issue is due to missing configuration for the x-axis. By default, Chart.js expects data to be indexed by integers starting from 0 unless explicitly set to use the x values from your data objects. A work around is to use the provided snippet below, which is as simple as adding the ff code to your chart.js file.
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  }
}

